# http request to get a list of playlist videos and titles

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I can't seem to get a playlist list of videos and their titles. Here is the http request (one of many) I've tried:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?&part=snippet&channelId=PLS3kdEFUhQD828Tj_46Si7Z8CdAgiVAPW&maxResults=50&key=(my key here)
```

I have the target channelId in, but I'm getting an invalid channel id error. I know it's the correct channelId though. Anyone know the proper request I should be using? I need to get a list of video ids and titles for each playlists I request.

Comment: I made a little progress with this http request: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=contentDetails,id,snippet&id=PLS3kdEFUhQD828Tj_46Si7Z8CdAgiVAPW&maxResults=50&key=(mykeyhere) but it only gives me the first video, not a list of all of them in the playlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [playlistItems API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) to get the list of videos :

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems
```

For your usecase :

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=PLS3kdEFUhQD828Tj_46Si7Z8CdAgiVAPW&key=YOUR_KEY

[Try it in the explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=PLS3kdEFUhQD828Tj_46Si7Z8CdAgiVAPW&_h=2&)